# Gnus summary buffer continuous pipes

Tags: emacs, gnus

I'd like to have continuous piping in my gnus summary buffer, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125222/customizing-gnus-summary-buffer?answertab=active#tab-top) user was attempting. I'm using OS X Emacs 24 window-system. Is it truly a font issue, as the solution's author claims? If so, what font would work (none that I've tried do the trick)? If it's not the font, are there any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: The unicode symbol FEFF with background color creates a thin vertical line that spans from the top to the bottom of the line.  When placing overlays on each line at the same horizontal position, it is possible to create a vertical line that stretches as far as the eye can see.  I have a custom minor mode that I use to create a vertical line that tracks the cursor position.  If you want it thicker, you can concatenate them.  This is done with overlays and propertize.  There are a few other unicode characters that accomplish the same goal -- it is called a zero-with space.

Comment: Here is an example that will place a thin bar to the left of the first position in the buffer -- this is longer/taller than a pipe `|` symbol because we are using the background color to create the appearance of a vertical line:  `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point-min) (point-min)) 'before-string (propertize (char-to-string ?\uFEFF) 'face '(:background "yellow") 'cursor t))`  You may also wish to take a look at the library `fill-column-indicator` -- the author of that library uses optional bitmap images to create a solid vertical line:  https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator

Answer (score 0):

It's both font choice and character choice.

In most fonts the `|` character (vertical bar) doesn't join up with itself; it's not intended for this character to do so.

If instead you use a character such as `┃` (U+2503 BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL) or `│` (U+2502 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL), then it is intended that these characters line up with themselves. The font itself cannot guarantee this (whoever draws the text might put too much space between successive lines of text), and emacs can't guarantee this because your chosen font might not even have a glyph for these characters. Usually they work though.

`C-x 8 RET` will allow you to type in a Unicode code point or a Unicode character name (with autocomplete), making it fairly easy to type these in.